# Data seems to have loaded but nothing retrieved with Cypher queries

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

New to Neo4j and this post, forgive me if I have not followed established conventions or norms reporting the following issue.

I loaded some data into the Neo4j database (v2.0.1) via a text file using the recommended approach from [this link](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html).

Everything seems to have loaded OK (see snippet from console below) but when I try to query the database, nothing is returned. From the Data Browser I enter the Cypher command

```
Match (n) Return n
```

Nothing is returned.

The Neo4j Dashboard shows over 500 nodes, 3000 properties, and 900 relationships. The REST API  also shows the nodes, relationships, and attributes (click on the bubbles icon in the upper left). Clicking on any of these nodes, relationships or attributes will trigger a Cypher query, but nothing will be returned.

The same `MATCH (n) Return n` query in the REST API also returns no nodes.

Is the data loading correctly? What am I doing wrong? I suspect there is some little trick I am just not getting. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I did run a few of the Cypher queries one at a time in the Data Browser (and REST API), and the nodes were created correctly, and I could query them. So I don't think there is an issue with the Cypher query itself (though I could be wrong).

```
******* Console feedback during load process **********

mac-pro:neo4j$ cat import.txt | bin/neo4j-shell -config conf/neo4j.properties -path      data/graph.db

NOTE: Local Neo4j graph database service at 'data/graph.db'
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands


neo4j-sh (?)$ BEGIN
Transaction started
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (n:Employee {ID:0, Name:'X', CompanyID:'211051', JobTitle:'SPECIALIST CONTRACTOR'…<other properties omitted for brevity>...});

+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+

Nodes created: 1

Properties set: 13

Labels added: 1

1906 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (n:Employee {ID:2, Name:'Y', CompanyID:'211036', JobTitle:'PROGRM. MNGR LEVEL CONTRACTOR', …<other properties omitted for brevity>...});

+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+

Nodes created: 1

Properties set: 13

Labels added: 1

.
.
.
<rest of the lines omitted>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you stop the shell and start the server afterwards? Or you can also just start the server and just start `bin/neo4j-shell` then it connects to the running server (omit `-path`) then.

Comment: Do you commit that transaction at the end?

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tips. Before running the script, I did stop the Neo4j server, and once the script had completed, I restarted the server with the bin/neo4j console command. The text file did have BEGIN at the top of the file, and COMMIT as the last command. Should there be a semicolon after COMMIT?

Comment: Mr Hunger-I did try your suggestion to keep the server running and omit the path statement. This loaded the nodes with no properties (didn't even create the node type - n:Employee in the example above). The same "Match (n) Return n" statement now returns 500 totally blank nodes. Per the instructions in the sample spreadsheet I did turn on node indexing (node_auto_indexing=true; node_keys_indexable=ID,Name) and I made sure every node I created had properties that started with ID, Name. Am I missing anything else? Any other setup/parameter I should check? Thanks again for the assistance.